# Randomly generate pdf on website

Tags: python, django, pdf, random, latex

I have created a latex file which creates a pdf by randomly selecting 10 subfiles from a pool of files. This works fine, and I am able to generate a random PDF every time I run my script. A breakdown of how this works:

- (within a latex article)
- Generate random number.
- Use this number to include a subfile.
- Repeat this for 10 times without repeating the random generated number.

**HOWEVER**, I now would like to implement this into my website. I would like a user of my website to "press a button", this runs the script and spits out a PDF for them to download. Any ideas how I might be able to achieve this?

(I am quite confident I need to move away from latex to achieve this. However, implementation is achievable, as shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23804/how-to-incorporate-tex-into-a-website , but there might be some security issues on the server )

Any advice is welcome.

**EDIT 1**

I came across this [website](http://www.mathmaster.org/dotevenodd/) and it shows very similarly what I would like to achieve.  There is a comment in the [About Us Page](http://www.mathmaster.org/about/) that they are using We used Python, Django and LaTeX to produce this work.

Does anyone have an idea how this is achieved?

Comment: does it need to pop up below the button Ajax style, or is a form-like appearance OK, where you click the "Generate" button and you are being redirected to the next page a second or two later where you can see the pdf?

Comment: redirected to a next page would be ok

Answer (score 0):

If going via the next page is fine, you can just use a HTML form, POST the
submit button into a php script, and call pdflatex from there using exec().

You copy the pdf generated by pdflatex into some location accessible by your webserver, and display it as you mentioned in the link in the original question.

Keep in mind that you should be careful with using exec(), as in make sure nobody will use that to execute commands on you machine (except the expected latex).

Comment: it will take a few seconds for pdflatex to finish though. maybe nowadays you find a nice way to display a progress bar or similar...

Comment: Hmm, I do think that I might be over complicating thing a bit when using Latex. I might follow @BeerSerc 's advice and have a  look at what php options are there. I did find this, which I found to be interesting: http://www.fpdf.org/

(My programming/language knowledge is barely existing, so there will definitely be a learning curve involved)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you don't want the exact ouput of your LaTeX solution, and just want to have a number in a pdf, you can look into calling

```
enscript my_text_file.txt -o - | ps2pdf - output.pdf
```

with a generated text file, using exec() in php again.